# How a compat ioctl gets called from the user space? Can anybody please provide some exmples?

Tags: linux, kernel

Suppose I have defined the following.

```
#define MY_IOCTL_CMD1 _IOR(MAGIC_NUMBER, 0x01, arg1)
#define MY_IOCTL_CMD2 _IOW(MAGIC_NUMBER, 0x02, arg2)
#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT
#define MY_COMPAT_IOCTL_CMD1 _IOR(MAGIC_NUMBER, 0x01, compat_arg1)
#define MY_COMPAT_IOCTL_CMD2 _IOW(MAGIC_NUMBER, 0x02, compat_arg2)
#endif
```

Now when we do ioctl from user space, we usually do

```
ioctl(fd, MY_IOCTL_CMD1, &arg1)
```

**Q:** Do we really need to have an ioctl with `MY_COMPAT_IOCTL_CMD1` as request?

In the devide code I have handlers defined as follows.
ioctl: device_ioctl

```
#ifdef CONFIG_COMPAT
compat_ioctl: device_compat_ioctl
#endif
```

Can anybody please provide some explanations around this?

Answer (score 8):

This compat stuff is for running a 32-bit program in a 64-bit kernel.  When you call the `ioctl(fd, MY_IOCTL_CMD1, &arg1)` from a 32-bit program on a 64-bit kernel, the kernel will divert the ioctl to the `.compat_ioctl` function in the `file_operations` struct.  This `compat_ioctl` function is responsible for copying the user argument `arg1` as if it were `compat_arg1`, which uses the 32-bit layout.  The `compat_arg1` typedef is defined in the kernel so that when compiled for 64-bit, the structure is exactly the same layout as the `arg1` compiled for 32-bit.

The definition of `MY_IOCTL_CMD1` will take the `sizeof arg1` into account when creating the cmd id.  When you compile a program for a 32-bit machine, the value for `MY_IOCTL_CMD1` will be different than if you compiled it for a 64-bit machine.  The 32-bit `MY_IOCTL_CMD1` should have the same value as the 64-bit `MY_COMPAT_IOCTL_CMD1` in the kernel, however.

There's never a need to use `compat_arg1` or `MY_COMPAT_IOCTL_CMD1` in a user-space application.  Those are only for code compiled in the kernel.